# Refresh ListView items on every second

Tags: android

Say I have data coming from server or local database. I am displaying them in listview. I have four-five textview in each listview item.Now I want to refresh listview item every second (requirement is something like this only).

How should I achieve this. notifyDataSetChanged() is I am aware about.

I want some robust solution which does not make the activity laggy.

Please guide.

Comment: I think best solution is notifyDataSetChanged only and I am having a doubt that is why you need to refresh listview in every second. I think you can refresh it whenever you receive any data.

Comment: Did you want updated data to be displayed first ? If this is the case activity will be laggy.

Answer (score 1):

I think use notifyDataSetChanged is the only way to do it.

Why do you think it may make the Activity laggy?

Comment: use handler with timer to refresh the list and also the ui.

Comment: It only change some attribute of the view. no object will be created during the notifyDataSetChanged if you implement the getView() method correctly.

Comment: I want to constantly update the background of TextView due to one requirement. This is the case for other textviews in listview too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should decrease your updating frequency. 1 second is too small for updates.
You can use [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) 
Execute this in every 1 sec. with the help of [postDelay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 private Thread t;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        t = new Thread(){   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized(this){ 
                        wait(2000); // set time whatever you want
                    }


                } 
                catch(InterruptedException ex){ 
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

               lv.clear();
               onCreate(null);
            }
        };
            t.start();
    }
```

try this ..

Comment: Yea this solution is in my mind. Passing null in onCreate refresh activity without fluctuating the view :)